# Windows PE files and their .text sections: how to predict which areas of them will change at runtime?

Tags: c++, file, dll, executable, portable-executable

I have a couple of PE files (DLL and EXE) and notice that their .text sections are not identical when comparing their file hash to their runtime post-load memory hash. Doing a char-by-char analysis I see that most of them are identical, but certain addresses have been changed at runtime.

It's my understanding that the changes are due to call-instruction address relocations happening during load. My questions:

- is a call-instruction address relocation the only thing that will potentially change to the .text section of a PE after it is loaded? Or are there other instructions that Windows will modify too?
- is there any way to **statically** examine a PE and detect which parts of the .text section will likely be changed at runtime (specific instructions I should be looking for?)
- are there any code guidelines I can follow, or compiler switches I can enable, which would minimize the number of relocations that may occur at runtime?

Use case:

I would like to verify code integrity of running program by comparing file hash of .text section in PE to memory hash of loaded PE's .text section. If I could statically identify certain instructions which trigger a relocation, I could skip over them during my hashing process. And also maybe use a strategy to minimize relocations overall.

Comment: Only the absolute address references within the code will change, i.e. the relocations. You can read the relocation table out of the PE to get all the offsets that get updated when a module doesn't load at its preferred load address. No, I do not happen to have code handy that shows how to do that, but the specification is available online.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So if I understand you correctly, I can parse the relocation table and that will give me offsets from the base address to the bytes that need to be changed in the .text section? So technically I could perform a precise static analysis of the PE and know exactly what will change simply by parsing that table? So in my hash function if I skip over those bytes my hashes should be identical?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I once tinkered with the PE format and created a proxy DLL that could load another DLL function by function in a lazy fashion. The key line of code did this:

```
rtn = (FARPROC)::VirtualAlloc(NULL, FUNC_CODE_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

It allocated memory that could be executed and then loaded the code of the function from the DLL into the allocated memory.
I am not completely sure if this would result in a change of .text. On one hand it's a heap allocation, on the other hand it is executable memory.

Here is a link to the article in case you want to tinker with it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273419/Dynamic-Libraries-with-Delayed-Function-Loading

Comment: On second thought, I think that mechanism would not touch the .text section. It would probably just affect the heap.